# wix build a report that each user see only is raws

Tags: velo

I want to build a report that each user see only is raws.
For example, I  have this report: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GcvTzb8hXCdiVXqjG9rKESqXQLL5lFYRDvF-NKw8FOM
I want that each user that login, for example, 1235566 from this report will get all there rews that belong to him. 
Please apply only if you know perfectly to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Lio, have you solved this yet or do you still need help?

It is not clear if you want to load the file from your google sheets link or you want to manage this using a data collection.

Here is a solution for you using the Wix Data Collections.

You can create a collection with similar columns using the Wix Data.

Here is an example of how to import data into a data collection:

- https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-code-tutorial-importing-and-exporting-collection-data-with-code

Once you have the data in the data collection you can query it based on whatever criteria  you need to. Here are some articles that show you how to query a data collection and the API reference:

- [Wix Data API Reference](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-data.html)
- [Working with the Data API](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-code-working-with-the-data-api)
- [Adding a Data Collection Search Capability](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-code-tutorial-adding-collection-data-search-functionality)

Lastly, The only way to ensure that you are showing the right information to the user who needs to see it is to make sure they are logged onto your site.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to add a Members Area to your page and enable sign up and login capabilities. With this you can then set up a [Members Only Page](https://support.wix.com/en/article/creating-members-only-pages-596999).

When this page is loaded you can use the [Wix Users API](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-users.html) to verfiy that the member is logged in and access the members unique ID such as their email Address.

If you use the email address instead of a number then the rest should be straight forward.

Good luck